# Как кинуть UI текст в скрипт повешенный на префаб? Unit2d

Tags: unity3d

есть такой скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LaserY : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text ScoreText;
    public int Score = 0;
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, 3f * Time.deltaTime));
        ScoreText.text = Score.ToString();
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D Meteor)
    {
        if (Meteor.gameObject.tag == "Meteor")
        {
            Destroy(Meteor.gameObject);
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Score++;
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно чтобы при попадании в метеорит он разрушался и в счёт добавлялось очко. Возникла проблема с тем, что я не знаю как установить текст в ScoreText.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я уже не пробовал. Проблема в том, что из-за того что скрипт повешен на префаб, текст не перетаскивается.

Comment: Пробывали прибавлять Score до удаления? Вы удаляется обьект до увеличения счёта от этого и не работает

Comment: Тут проблема в другом, я не могу перетащить UI текст из Canvas, в переменную public Text ScoreText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не можете перенести объект со сцены в префаб. Вам либо нужно сделать тот объект префабом либо написать новый скрипт(который будет проверять OnCollision Enter с этого скрипта) и повесить его на UI text. Рекомендую использовать event для OnCollisionEnter2D, что в разы упростит задачу.

Comment: А не расскажите поподробнее про event для OnColisionEnter2d?

Comment: Сделайте отдельный скрипт, который будет хранить 2 event Action<Collider2D> для входа и выхода из коллизии. Также в скрипте должен быть  OnColisionEnter2d и OnColisionExit2d и когда будет столкновение коллизий, будет выполняться event. В итоге использовать эти events в других скриптах. Рекомендую почитать статьи или посмотреть видео про Event System.